# Java ANPR project with webcam connectivity

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am working on a project named as ANPR and while searching for guide I found a [link](http://javaanpr.sourceforge.net/) on JavaANPR. Its a great project, but I want that project to be connected with my webcam so the number plates can be recognized directly from webcam not from still image.

Please any one if there is a way that I can connect my webcam directly to this project then share it with me.. I'll really appreciate that..!

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Webcam Capture in Java](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture),
you should easily be able to build a simple program using my [fork of JavaANPR](https://github.com/oskopek/javaanpr).

Using the code examples given by both Webcam Capture and JavaANPR, the main part of your code would look something like this:

```
Intelligence intel = new Intelligence();
Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
webcam.open();

CarSnapshot carSnap = new CarSnapshot(webcam.getImage());
String numberPlate = intel.recognize(carSnap);
```

Now the `numberPlate` string contains the recognized number plate text.